# How do you remove the first number followed by comma in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

If I have strings `["32145","yes","no","0"]` how would like: `,"yes","no","0"`? Right now I have the regex below, but that gives me `,yes,no,`

`.replace(/["'\\[\\]\d]/g,"")`

How do I just remove the first number and first comma following that number?

Comment: A good resource i use when testing regex is an [online regex editor](https://regex101.com/) to quickly see how its interacting. Just adding it in case you find it useful.

Comment: @Emma yes I would

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe,

```
\["\d+",|[\]"]
```

being replaced with an empty string would work OK.

```js
const regex = /\["\d+",|[\]"]/g;
const str = `["32145","yes","no","0"] `;
const subst = ``;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UYArIB/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: This still keeps all the quotation marks, also I'm not looking to add the brackets back

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution without regex using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```js
var str = '["32145","yes","no","0"]';

var result = JSON.parse(str); // Convert string to array.
result.shift(); // Remove first array element.
result = result.toString(); // Convert array to string.

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply parse the value and remove the first element which is a number

```js
let firstNumRemover = (str) => {
  let removeFurther = true
  return JSON.parse(str).filter(v => {
    if (!isNaN(v) && removeFurther) {
      removeFurther = false
      return false
    }
    return true
  }).toString()
}

console.log(firstNumRemover(`["32145","yes","no","0"]`))
console.log(firstNumRemover(`["Some random text", "32145","yes","no","0"]`))
```